# Explore .raw file?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, filesystems, raw

I have a .raw file that is a snapshot of a hard drive. I'm trying to explore the contents of it on my Ubuntu computer, however I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Is there a way to mount it and explore it that way? `cat` shows many files and their contents, along with directory paths, so I know it's recoverable.

Thanks

Comment: Migrate to Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: @slayernoah it is perfectly on topic here. http://meta.superuser.com/a/2645/19943

Comment: hmm. Single partition or a few?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if its a single partition or a few. I'm rather find of kpartx for actual raw images with more than one drive `kpartx -a -v foo.raw` load up the .raw file, then you can mount the /dev/mapper devices as if they were normal drives. There's a pretty nice, more complete set of examples on the [nfolampblog](https://nfolamp.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/mounting-raw-image-files-and-kpartx/)

If its a single drive joejoe21b's answer should work

Comment: `kpartx -l <file>` does not show any output, nor does the command in your answer.

Comment: Are you sure its actually a valid disk image?